# onCreateDialog and dynamic dialogs (Android)

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have a little problem. In my program I defined

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    if (id == CONTEXT_MENU_ID) {
        return createMyDialog();
    }
    return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}
```

and then show the dialog calling

```
showDialog(CONTEXT_MENU_ID)
```

My problem is that sometimes I want to change the texts of the Dialog dynamically between executions. But with that method the Dialog is never recreated. How can I make the createMyDialog() to be called before showing the Dialog?

Thanks

Comment: dinamical? Seriously? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change dialog settings (text, etc.) you need to do it in [onPrepareDialogMethod](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareDialog%28int,%20android.app.Dialog,%20android.os.Bundle%29) it will be called each time you call `showDialog` method

Answer (score 0):

This might be worth a try. I haven't tested it out. To the dialog if you set the textview as its content, then you can set an id to it.

```
TextView text = new TextView(this);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams vp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
text.setLayoutParams(vp);
text.setText("HI");
text.setId(1005);    
dialog.setContentView(text);
```

So the next time when you try to update the textview, you might be able to access it using the id.

```
((TextView)dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(1005))
        .setText("New Text");
```